# 8086 listen to keyboard while drawing

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, x86-16

I'm familiar with INT 16h that waits for keyboard input, but I'm developing a game and I would like there to be a game loop, that animates things on the screen, and whenever there is a keyboard hit, the 8086 should go to my interrupt handler and tell me which key has been pressed to update my data accordingly.

How could I do so ?

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480576/custom-keyboard-interrupt-handler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also poll for input with 1 in AH instead of 0, when calling INT 16.

```
INT 16h / AH = 01h - check for keystroke in the keyboard buffer.

    return:

        ZF = 1 if keystroke is not available.
        ZF = 0 if keystroke available.
        AH = BIOS scan code.
        AL = ASCII character.
        (if a keystroke is present, it is not removed from the keyboard buffer).
```

[(Source.)](http://h4xxel.org/asm/8086_bios_and_dos_interrupts.html)

Answer (score 2):

In MS-DOS you can write your own custom keyboard interrupt handler, and in your custom keyboard interrupt handler code you can, for example:

1. set a flag to inform the main loop/draw loop that a key has been pressed, together with the scan code of the key, or...
2. Modify the code of the main loop/draw loop in your custom interrupt handler according to the scan code of the key.

For more info on writing a custom [keyboard] interrupt handler, see eg.:

- [Is it possible to make a custom Interrupt in Assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464329/is-it-possible-to-make-a-custom-interrupt-in-assembly)
- [Replacing the Timer Interrupt Handler in DOS With GNU (GCC and GAS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406055/replacing-the-timer-interrupt-handler-in-dos-with-gnu-gcc-and-gas)
- [pages 31-39 of chapter 16 of some assembly tutorial](http://employees.oneonta.edu/higgindm/assembly/Chapter16.ppt)
- [part 17.4 of Expert MS-DOS Programming](http://es.scribd.com/doc/53566261/Expert-MS-DOS-Programming)